# How to know if a specific Java class is thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

1. Is it true that all classes not under java.util.concurrent are unsafe in a multi-threaded environment?
2. If number 1 is wrong, how do you know if a specific class is thread-safe?

Comment: Read the documentation. If it says it's thread safe, it's thread safe. Otherwise you should assume it is not.

Comment: [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is a good example. It's there from the beginning of Java, not in the concurrent package and you can read in the documantation all about its thread safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is not accurate to claim that all classes not under
  java.util.concurrent are unsafe in a multi-threaded environment in
  Java. Whether a class is thread-safe or not depends on its design and
  how it handles concurrent access by multiple threads. Java's
  java.util.concurrent package contains a set of classes that are
  explicitly designed and tested to work correctly in multi-threaded
  environments.  However, there are many other classes in Java, both in
  the standard library and in custom code, that can be used safely in
  multi-threaded environments if they are used correctly and with
  proper synchronization mechanisms. These classes may not be
  explicitly labeled as "thread-safe," but they can still be used
  safely with the right precautions.
- Classes in java.util.concurrent are explicitly designed for
  multi-threaded use, not all other classes are inherently unsafe. You
  should carefully **review the documentation**, source code, and
  synchronization mechanisms used by a class to determine whether it is
  safe to use in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: It is dubious to rely on the source code to tell you if a class is thread-safe or not.  If the javadocs don't mention thread-safety, then the (undocumented) thread-safety characteristics of a Java SE class *could* change from one version to the next.